# Program 'composer.bat' failed to run

Tags: composer-php, php-7.4

I have installed composer and set environment variable. But when use "Composer install" command. I am getting below error.

I also reviewed the extensions and all the relevant (openssl) extensions are enable.

> Program 'composer.bat' failed to run: The system cannot find the file
>   specifiedAt line:1 char:1
>   + composer
>   + ~~~~~~~~. At line:1 char:1
>   + composer
>   + ~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Please help me to fix this issue

Thanks in advance.